# Mongoose Database Connection and Schema

Tags: javascript, mongodb, node.js, mongoose

Hi There: I'm having a difficult time online finding out how to perform a simple database connection, schema creation, and basic CRUD using mongoose with node.js. Right now I have the following code but am getting the error:

"TypeError: object is not a function

at Schema.CALL_NON_FUNCTION_AS_CONSTRUCTOR (native).."

```
// Launch express and server
var express = require('express');
var app = express.createServer();


//connect to DB
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var db = mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/napkin_0.1');


// Define Model
var Schema = mongoose.Schema,
    ObjectId = Schema.ObjectId;

User = new Schema({
  'title': { type: String, index: true },
  'data': String,
  'tags': [String],
  'user_id': ObjectId
});

//Define Collection
mongoose.model('Document', User);


var user = new User();
user.title = "TEST TITLE";
user.save();


//Launch Server
app.listen(3002);
```

Comment: I don't see where you've defined "User"

Comment: Isn't this the definition: User = new Schema({
  'title': { type: String, index: true },
  'data': String,
  'tags': [String],
  'user_id': ObjectId
});

Comment: A little tip for troubleshooting nodejs apps: read the entire stack trace and look for the exact location of the error. Usually it's just staring you in the face.

Comment: oh, sorry, dunno how I missed that. There's a good looking answer now :)

Answer (score 10):

You are trying to instantiate an instance of the Schema. I would change

```
User = new Schema({
```

To

```
UserSchema = new Schema({
```

and later on call

```
var User = mongoose.model('user', UserSchema);
```

and finally

```
var user = new User();
```

Answer (score 1):

After your schema definition.

```
//Define Collection
mongoose.model('Document', User);
```

The above code is not for defining collection, it is to initialize the model object.

Change it as follows:

```
//Create Model Object
var UserModel = mongoose.model('user_model_name', User); // 2nd param -> User is a schema object
```

Then create the Document object out of model object. 
As follows:

```
var user_doc = new UserModel();
```

Then you can use getters/setters and methods.

```
user_doc.title = 'your text for title';
user_doc.save();
```